# Fix compiled MVC ASP.NET site without the original code to compile

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, reflection, nopcommerce

I messed up pretty badly. I completely deleted my copy of the source code after making many changes to the source and getting my clients site up and running. He is now wanting some additional changes made but without that original source code I am not able to make the changes and still keep the changes I already made for him on the compiled version.

I am trying to add this code to the global.asax file

```
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.RawUrl.ToLower().EndsWith("discover"))
        {
            Response.RedirectPermanent("discover.html");
        }
```

is there any way of doing this without losing what is already compiled?
this is on MVC3 using the script nopcommerce 2.30

Comment: You can use the Reflector, jetbrains dotpeek or ILSPY to decompile the DLL, but you would have to create the solution again by copying the code from decompiltion. it might be a good idea to do so for future updates. [Reflector](http://www.reflector.net/), [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

Comment: ... just making a note of your name for future ref. but at least you admit your folly - lol

Answer (score 0):

as @Scorpion-Prince noted, you should use a decompiler and decompile your dll's, i have had great experience using [JetBrains DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) but you can try other decompilers as well.